# how to send the var value full of lists to tabcontrol

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol, dynamically-generated

i want create a dynamical datagridview in dynamical tabpage and show the list of var value in my form
this is my code but it's not working,no error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfxM9.png)

Comment: So you can see the grid view  but no columns ? or you can see the columns but no data ?

Comment: nothing at all , no data grid no tabpage i dont know why

Comment: you see my pic of mycode?

Comment: Yes i can, i tried your code and it worked. Can you show where this code is placed and how are you calling it ? You can paste code below your answer, no need for images.

Comment: i run the code on butten_click and it show's nothing - code is runing but no data grid

Comment: Do you have controls in your form ? Like Panel, TableLayoutPanel ? Try adding a panel somewhere and instead of `this.Controls.Add(dynamicTab);` use `somePanel.Controls.Add(dynamicTab);`

Comment: yes that worked but if i want to create another tabpage and DGV what should i do?

Comment: Check answer to see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, it seems it is a designing issue and the `TabControl` is not visible for some reason.

Try adding a Panel through the designer and then replace:

```
this.Controls.Add(dynamicTab);
```

With:

```
somePanel.Controls.Add(dynamicTab);
```

If you want to create another Page:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreatePageGrid(qsreach.ToList(), "Page 1");
    CreatePageGrid(qsreach2.ToList(), "Page 2");
    CreatePageGrid(qsreach3.ToList(), "Page 3");
}

TabControl dynamicTab;

private void CreatePageGrid(object dataSource, string pageName)
{
    if (dynamicTab == null)
    {
        dynamicTab = new TabControl();
        this.Controls.Add(dynamicTab);
    }

    DataGridView dvg = new DataGridView();
    TabPage t2 = new TabPage();
    dvg.DataSource = dataSource;
    t2.Text = pageName;
    t2.Controls.Add(dvg);
    dynamicTab.Controls.Add(t2);
}
```

Comment: @InvBoy01001 Maybe you can accept the answer now in order to close this question.

Comment: how can i do that?